# Bayes theorem, disease probability

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

There is a new test for a disease. This disease occurs in 3% of the population. We have experimental evidence that

If someone has the disease, then the test will give a positive result 95% of the time, and a negative result 5% of the time

If someone does not have the disease, the test is positive 6% of the time, and negative 94% of the time

We take a person “off the street” and run the test on them.

**1. If the test is positive, what is the probability that they have the disease?**

**2. If the test is negative, what is the probability that they have the disease?**

Now assume we have some additional evidence that changes the likelihood of a person that we are testing from 3% to 30%. What are the probabilities above now?

---

---

As solutions I got:

```
 1. (0.03 * 0.95/0.95) * 0.03 / ((0.03 * 0.95) + (0.97 * 0.06)) = 32.87%

 2. (0.03 * 0.05/0.05) * 0.03 / ((0.03 * 0.05) + (0.97 * 0.94)) = 0.00098

 3. (0.3 * 0.95/0.95) * 0.3 / ((0.3 * 0.95) + (0.7 * 0.06)) = 27.52%

 4. (0.3 * 0.05/0.05) * 0.3 / ((0.3 * 0.05) + (0.7 * 0.94)) = 13.372%
```

**Are my results correct?** Thanks

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279851/applied-probability-bayes-theorem/2279888#2279888

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32933/describing-bayesian-probability

Answer (score 1):

> 1. $(0.03 * 0.95/0.95) * 0.03 / ((0.03 * 0.95) + (0.97 * 0.06)) = 32.87\%$
> 2. $(0.03 * 0.05/0.05) * 0.03 / ((0.03 * 0.05) + (0.97 * 0.94)) = 0.00098$
> 3. $(0.3 * 0.95/0.95) * 0.3 / ((0.3 * 0.95) + (0.7 * 0.06)) = 27.52\%$
> 4. $(0.3 * 0.05/0.05) * 0.3 / ((0.3 * 0.05) + (0.7 * 0.94)) = 13.372\%$
>
> **Are my results correct?** Thanks

No.   I am not sure what you are even trying to do for the numerator; but stop doing that.

1. $\mathsf P(D\mid T)~{=\dfrac{\mathsf P(D)\mathsf P(T\mid D)}{\mathsf P(D)\mathsf P(T\mid D)+\mathsf P(D^\complement)\mathsf P(T\mid D^\complement)}\\=\dfrac{(0.03 * 0.95) }{ ((0.03 * 0.95) + (0.97 * 0.06))}}$

and so forth.